# Which R and RStudio version to install for Windows 32 bit?

Tags: r, rstudio, 32-bit

I'm taking a course on R programming and it requires me to install "devtools" package. I was using Anaconda to learn Python and used the same to use R. But I wasn't able to install the package and came to know that Anaconda only supports certain versions of RStudio. So, now I'll have to download R and RStudio separately. My system info -

**Windows edition -** Windows 7 professional

**System type** - 32-bit OS

Can someone help me with the version of R and RStudio I should download now?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: This is a fairly broad question. A quick google search yields a lot of tutorials on how to install R/RStudio on various Windows versions, e.g. [here](https://medium.com/@GalarnykMichael/install-r-and-rstudio-on-windows-5f503f708027). Can you edit your post to detail what you've tried, and what errors/issues you've encountered? Stack Overflow is not a free tutorial service to help with (what sounds a lot like) an IT request.

Comment: The real solution is to update your system urgently: Windows 7 is ancient, and [is no longer supported](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-7-end-of-life-support-information). Running unsupported operating systems is a major security risk.

Comment: @MauritsEvers I have mentioned that I used Anaconda to install RStudio, but the package that is required for the course was not available in the version that Anaconda supported. It was while searching the internet for solutions that I came to know Anaconda doesn't support the latest version of R. I'm not a techie person and a complete newbie trying to learn something out of my expertise. Felt your comment to be a little harsh :(  Anyways, thank you for responding!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last version of RStudio to support a 32-bit OS was 1.1.463. You can download it from [here](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/older-versions/) (scroll down until you find it).

You should be able to install the latest release of R from [here](https://cran.rstudio.com/), just make sure that you install the 32-bit version.

From experience, R/Rstudio 1.1.463 works OK on 32-bit computers, but you might run into som troubles, both with R itself and some packages that rely on newer versions of RStudio. You might find some help [here](https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#Does-R-run-under-Windows-Vista_003f) should you experience troubles with R itself.

I hope this helps. But in any case, your best option would be to upgrade your system if possible.

Comment: Really appreciate your help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in jpiversen answer, your specs seem a bit outdated.

But RStudio luckily also has a [cloud version](https://rstudio.cloud), so you don't need to install anything.

You might want to look into that.

Comment: This is cool. I'll definitely try it out. Thank you for sharing!